# Generate pseudo-random integer from another pseudo-random integer and a key

Tags: random, uniform-distribution

Suppose that there's a given function `R()` that generates pseudo-random integers in range `[0, 999]` (which I don't have control of its internals, e.g. its seed):

```
r1 = R()  # r1 = 671
r2 = R()  # r2 = 983
r3 = R()  # r3 = 023
...
```

I want to find a mapping function `M(r, key)` which takes the output from `R()` and a my own provided fixed `key`, and then generates another pseudorandom integer in range `[0, 999]`.

The requirement is that for a given `key` and a fixed integer `r`, `M(r, key)` is deterministic. But it should have pseudorandom characteristics, that is, uniform distribution, being hard-to-guess from `r` (seemingly random), etc. And whenever I change the `key`, a whole different pseudorandom integers in range `[0, 999]` are returned.

The format of `key` is optional; it can be string, an integer in `[0, 1000)`, or whatever I choose.

Note that the output need NOT to be cryptographically secure. But it should be reasonably uniform pseudorandom for a scientific simulation. The later is not very strict though.

I'm thinking of using `HMAC_SHA1(key: my_key, message: r)`. But I don't know how to convert the result to an integer in `[0, 1000)` such that it satisfies the mentioned requirements.

What do you propose?

Comment: I  believe that it's impossible to make $M(r, key)$ deterministic if $M()$ depends on $R()$ if you cannot seed $R()$.

Comment: The point is that `M(r, key)` is deterministic for a given fixed `key` and `r`, not for `R()`. `M` depends on a fixed integer `r`, not on the function `R()`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to reduce the 160 bit output of the SHA-1 HMAC uniformly to the range [0, 999] is to take the 10 least significant bits of the SHA digest and if that number is outside the range [0, 999] simply feed it back into the HMAC, repeating if necessary until you get a number in range. Here's some pseudocode of the algorithm.

```
function randmap(key, r)
{
    do {
        r = hmac(key, r);
        # Get 10 least significant bits, so the result is in [0, 1023]
        r = r & 0x3ff;
    } while (r >= 1000);
    return r;
}
```

If you don't like the idea of throwing away 150 bits of the SHA digest, another option is to use XOR-folding: break the digest into 16 10-bit blocks and XOR them together. But that's probably overkill for this non-cryptographic application.

---

If you want `M(r, key)` to map each $r$ in [0, 999] to a unique $q$ in [0, 999], the simplest way is to create a permutation of [0, 999] and use $r$ to index into that list. Here's some simple Python 3 code that does that. I've set the `size` parameter to 20 rather than 1000 to keep the test output manageable, but this code is suitable for list sizes up into the millions.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import seed, shuffle

def build_mapper(key, size):
    seed(key)
    mapper = list(range(size))
    shuffle(mapper)
    return mapper

# Test

size = 20
mapper = build_mapper('test', size)
for i in range(size):
    print(i, mapper[i])
```

**output**

```
0 11
1 0
2 16
3 17
4 18
5 13
6 14
7 10
8 4
9 9
10 5
11 19
12 3
13 2
14 15
15 12
16 1
17 6
18 7
19 8
```

Note that the Python `random.seed` function accepts any hashable object as its parameter, so you can feed it an integer or a string.

If you need to work with a much larger list size there are methods to create a permutation mapping that don't require a list in RAM. Such techniques are used in [Format-preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). For example, you could use a Feistel network with a simple "round function".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how they're supposed to lead to uniform distribution?

Comment: @MassoodKhaari Let `q = randmap(key, r)`. For a fixed $r$, if $key$ is randomly distributed then so is $q$. But I suspect I've misunderstood your question (again). Do you want $randmap(key, r)$ to map each $r$ in [0, 1000] to a unique $q$ in [0, 1000]? In other words, each $key$ specifies a permutation of [0, 1000]?